# Concrete category with a certain property involving monomorphisms

Tags: category-theory, terminology, monomorphisms

I am looking for a way to describe concrete categories with "good properties" in my work, and one of the properties I found that I want a concrete category $C$ to have is that whenever $g$ is a monomorphism in $C$, $f$ is a morphism in Set and $g \circ f$ is a monomorphism in $C$, it follows that $f$ is a morphism in $C$.

Effectively, I want the concrete category $C$ to be such that whenever $X$ is an object in $C$ and $A$ and $B$ are subobjects of $X$ such that $A \subseteq B$ in Set (as subobjects of $X$), then $A \subseteq B$ in $C$ (as subobjects of $X$). In particular, if $A$ and $B$ are subsets of the set $X$ such that $A \subseteq B$ as sets, I want the the inclusion map of $A$ into $B$ to be a morphism in the category $C$.

So, is there a name for such a property of a concrete category? Or perhaps a name for such a property in any subcategory of another category?

Comment: Do you have an example of a concrete category in which your property doesn't hold?

Comment: This property is satisfied in any variety of universal algebras. It is not satisfied in the category of topological spaces or the category of posets.

Comment: As Geoffrey said, the property doesn't hold in the category of topological spaces. However, I thought it was satisfied in the category of posets, isn't it?

Comment: This is pretty much the "coherence" condition in Abstract Elementary Classes (AECs): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_elementary_class and has been called that in category-theoretic treatment of such classes (unfortunately sometimes clashing with the use of "coherence" in category theory). In particular, any class of first-order structures with embeddings (or elementary embeddings) will satisfy this property.

Comment: The category of posets has an issue, because there are different types of monomorphism: ones that reflect the order (regular monos) and ones that might not (just normal monos). For example, take $A = X = \{a < b\}$ and take $B = \{a, b\}$ (with no relation between them). Then $A = B = X$ as underlying sets (so the inclusions commute), but $A \to X$ does not factor through $B$ in the category of posets. If you restrict to posets with regular monos then you have your property (this is a particular case of my previous comment).

Comment: Interesting to know about that condition in AECs! And thanks for the example on the category of posets, it is just like in the case of topological spaces, where a finer topology on a topological space gives a monomorphism such that the identity function does not factor through. I wonder if there are categories where this condition is not satisfied by some regular monomorphisms.